# Find all roles in context.user

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, authentication, security-roles

i have to check all the roles for a user.currently im checking isinrole.
but i want to find all roles.to hide show some data.

```
 if (Context.User.IsInRole("Travel_Admin"))
                    {
                        visibleTables.Remove(item_level10);
                        visibleTables.Add(item_level1);
                        visibleTables.Add(item_level2);
                        visibleTables.Add(item_level3);
                        visibleTables.Add(item_level4);
                        visibleTables.Add(item_level5);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        visibleTables.Remove(item_level1);
                        visibleTables.Remove(item_level2);
                        visibleTables.Remove(item_level3);
                        visibleTables.Remove(item_level4);
                        visibleTables.Remove(item_level5);
                        visibleTables.Remove(item_level12);
                        visibleTables.Remove(item_level10);
                    }
```

I need to find all roles in context.user for that specific user.
Note:I am beginner in role based authentication.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to find all the roles of your user, use the following:

```
Roles.GetRolesForUser()
```

It will give you a string array of all its roles. You can specify a user for the mtehod.

You can use it in a method like:

```
foreach(string role in Roles.GetRolesForUser())
{
   // do treatment for this role of the user
}
```

See doc here for this method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.getrolesforuser.aspx

In MX2 solution, you browse all types of roles defined, not only this user roles!

You can find Roles methods here in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.Security.Roles_methods.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 foreach (var item in Roles.GetAllRoles())
 {
      if(Context.User.IsInRole(item))
      {
            //code
      }
      else
      {
            //code
      }
 }
```